# Is there a way to download a repo with its submodules through gitlab APIs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Assume there is a huge repo with submodules at gitlab, I want to download a specific version of this repo.

A trivial but slow way is:

```
git clone --recursive <repo-site>  # very slow
git checkout <some-commit>
git submodule update
```

Another fast way is to use `git archive` to download a `tar` file, but the file doesn't include submodules. Therefore I need to manually find the corresponding commits of submodules and `git archive` them.

So I wonder if there is a fast and automatic way to do this? Maybe gitlab API is a start, but I failed to query the submodules of a repo.

Comment: Submodules can be located in different repositories, so I think you are left with _slow_ "clone"